# Rest API - Duplicate products and partners are added to opportunities

Tags: rest-api, rest, rest-service, sfrestrequest, chatter-rest-api

I'm trying to add 2 products and 2 partners to an existing opportunity through REST API. Even though both products and partners are different, they have the same name and product code in SFDC. Strangely, total_price is different and role is different however names and product codes are same.

Can anyone help fix this issue?

Here's the code I used to add products:

```
JSONObject resellerProduct = newJSONObject(); 

resellerProduct.put("OpportunityId", "00618000002WleCAAS");
resellerProduct.put("PricebookEntryId", "001b000002PA0Mn");
resellerProduct.put("Product_Code__c", "900-1234");
resellerProduct.put("Quantity", "1");
resellerProduct.put("TotalPrice", "4000.05");

sfdcConnection.createSfdcObject("OpportunityLineItem", resellerProduct);

JSONObject customerProduct = new JSONObject();

customerProduct.put("OpportunityId", "00618000002WleCAAS");
customerProduct.put("PricebookEntryId", "001w000901PA0yz");
customerProduct.put("Product_Code__c", "102-5432");
customerProduct.put("Quantity", "1");
customerProduct.put("TotalPrice", "1116.72");

sfdcConnection.createSfdcObject("OpportunityLineItem", customerProduct);
```

Here's how these products are attached to this opportunity in SFDC:

```
Product     Sales Price      List Price      Product Code       
ABC         4000.05           6500.00         900-1234          
ABC         1116.72           2463.32         900-1234
```

Comment: Without code all we can say to so check the debug logs and trace the code to see what is going on. Please post relevant code and be specific or this question may be closed by the community

Comment: Hi, Here's the code I used to add products to an opportunity:

Comment: Are you sure you aren't displaying the OOB OLI field `Product Code` instead of the custom `Product_Code__c`?  The former is derived from the value of the PBE (which points at a Product2)